# Can I add folders to the Content section of the Solution Explorer?

Tags: directory, solution-explorer

So a pretty simple question hopefully.

I'm creating a game that contains several mini-games within it. So I'm operating on several gamestates and as the individual games get larger and larger so do all the files that come with them, fonts, images, sounds etc.

Instead of having all my images, fonts and sounds being displayed in one huge list under the content section of the solution explorer I would like to have them in folders. So when I look over to the content section I have a folder for each game. Game1, Game2, Game3. Then within those I can have all the content. Is this possible?

Comment: Right-click on your solution, select "Add", then select "New Solution Folder".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Comment: I knew I was being stupid! This won't affect how I refer to the textures in the Load Content section will it? 

For example I currently have a image that I refer to as ("para") if I put it in a folder called game 1 will I need to refer to it as ("game 1/ para") or do I still refer to it as para?

Comment: If you're referring to it in code, no it won't have any affect.  It's simply an organizational tool.  I use it for our main application at work (it's an n-tier system, so I have a solution folder for each layer).  If it's a resource (like an image), it shouldn't affect it either, unless you create the corresponding solution folder on the hard drive and move the image into it.